# Run and Debug a program Intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

i've a small problem with my Intellij every time i Run my android program on Intellij it ask me to Debug otherwise the application will not work. Is there any solution to that problem?
when i Run it on my Device i get:

the application is waiting for Debugger to attach

Comment: remove applicaition and its caches from your phone, then restart your ide, it will be fixed

Comment: i've tryed that not working

Comment: This happens from time to time in Android Studio aswell (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA). To fix the issue, you have to unninstall the application, if that doesn't work, restarting your phone, always does!

Comment: @Marko ok thank you it's fixed working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are starting it with the debugging option in IntelliJ. If you start with the regular run button it shouldn't try to connect to the debugger.

EDIT: then try on your android device to go to the developer options and disable debugging there.

EDIT2: kill the adb.exe process on your PC?

EDIT3: build -> clean ??

Comment: this is the problem, i'm starting it with the regular run button! but in the device i get the message telling me that it's waiting for debug to start

Comment: nop not from the device also, still the same problem